# How to run odaslive program from c file

Tags: c++, execl

So I am trying to call a program from within a c file I am making but the only way I've been able to do that is by using the system() function which causes error on its own. To run the program in terminal I use;

```css
~/odas/bin/odaslive -vc ~/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg
```

This is what I am currently trying to use to run that same program, it compiles and will run in terminal but nothing happens.

```css
pid_t pid=fork();

if (pid==0){
    //static char *argv[] ={"echo","-vc ~/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg", NULL};
    execl("~/odas/bin", "~/odas/bin/odaslive", "-vc", "~/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg", (char *)NULL);
    exit(127);

} else {
    waitpid(pid,0,0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`execl` requires file path in the first argument.

It doesn't expand ~ with the home for path. The full path must be supplied.

Check a returned value and `errno`. It will inform you about a failure reason if any.

```
int ret = execl("/home/username/odas/bin/odaslive", "/home/username/odas/bin/odaslive", "-vc", "/home/username/odas/config/odaslive/matrix_creator.cfg", (char *)NULL);
```